# Is it possible to recognize the material with google vision api?

Tags: react-native, google-vision, vision-api

The following is a list of object recognition supported by **google vision api**.

```
 - Table of contents.
 - Face detection 1.
 - Landmark detection 2.
 - Logo detection 3.
 - Label detection 4.
 - Text detection.
 - Document text detection (dense text / handwriting)
 - Image properties 5
```

I want to recognize the material of scanned product in **React-Native**.

Is it possible to detect material also? Like "**Paper cup**", "**glass bottle**", "**zink key**" etc.